# Achieving XML format in C#

Tags: c#, xml

How can i achieve a format like this in C#?

suppose this is the output:

```
<Region id="1" name="Africa"/>
```

so far this is my C# code:

```
using (XmlWriter xml_writer = XmlWriter.Create(str_builder))
{
    xml_writer.WriteStartDocument();
    xml_writer.WriteStartElement("RegionList");

    foreach (var get_regions in qdb_conn.Regions()) 
    {
        xml_writer.WriteStartElement("Region");
        xml_writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    xml_writer.WriteEndElement();
    xml_writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you really *have* to use `XmlWriter`, I simply wouldn't. I'd use LINQ to XML instead:

```
XElement region = new XElement("Region",
                               new XAttribute("id", 1),
                               new XAttribute("name", "Africa"));
```

Job done - you can then write that to whatever you want. Having said that, it should be easy to get your existing code to work. Just change the loop to something like:

```
foreach (var get_regions in qdb_conn.Regions()) 
{
    xml_writer.WriteStartElement("Region");
    xml_writer.WriteAttributeString("id", XmlConvert.ToString(get_regions.Id));
    xml_writer.WriteAttributeString("name", get_regions.Name);
    xml_writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```